# How to wait for a function, which calls itself recursively with setTimeout, to complete?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, animation, recursion

I am new to Javascript and currently working on a website, that changes how it looks by itself over time.

One part of this page is a "Typewriter", that writes out a text letter by letter.
This is the code for this Typewriter:

```
function typeWriter(element, txt) {
    if (txt.length > 1) {
        element.textContent += txt.charAt(0);
        var newText = txt.slice(1,txt.length);
        setTimeout(typeWriter, 150 , element, newText);
    } else {
        element.textContent += txt.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Now I want to wait for the typewriter-function to finish with its text before doing another change to let's say my background-color.

```
function runThis(){
    var line1 = document.getElementById("line1");
    typeWriter(line1, "This should be written first, before continuing");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

To my understanding, the setTimeout makes my typewriter async, so if I do it as in the example above the third line of code will run as soon as the typewriter hits the first setTimeout.

I tried to realize this with the async/await terms and promises. But even after I resolve the promise, my "runThis" function won't continue after the typewriter finishes.

```
function typeWriter(element, txt) {
    return new Promise (function(resolve,reject) {
        if (txt.length > 1) {
            element.textContent += txt.charAt(0);
            var newText = txt.slice(1,txt.length);
            setTimeout(typeWriter, 150, element, newText);
        } else {
            element.textContent += txt.charAt(0);
            resolve();
        }
    })
}


async function runThis() {
    var line1 = document.getElementById("line1");
    await typeWriter(line1, "papupa");
    console.log("waiting over")
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Can you please help me figure out what's wrong here?
Thank you very much

Comment: That is because the promise returned by the first call to `typeWriter` is never resolved, you're only resolving the last promise that is created.

Comment: Thank you for explaining where I went wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `setTimeout` in a promise. This will allow you to use the `async/await` syntax to express the intention of your code more clearly, almost as if it was running synchronously.

```js
async function runThis() {
  var line1 = document.getElementById("line1");
  await typeWriter(line1, "papupa");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

async function typeWriter(element, txt) {
  for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    element.textContent += txt[i]; // this is shorthand for txt.charAt(i)
    await pause();
  }
}

function pause() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 150);
  });
}
```

Comment: I think I like this solution the most. It's really straight forward to understand. Is there anything I should be careful about in terms of best practices, when using this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the function to run at the end as another parameter.

```
function typeWriter(element, txt, callback) {
    if (txt.length > 1) {
        element.textContent += txt.charAt(0);
        var newText = txt.slice(1,txt.length);
        setTimeout(typeWriter, 150 , element, newText, cb);
    } else {
        element.textContent += txt.charAt(0);
        callback();
    }
}

typeWriter(el, "ABCDEF", runthis);
```

Comment: so if I write multiple lines with various changes in between, I would need a different "runthis" for every time I run my typeWriter, right?

Comment: Yes. You can have a single function that takes a parameter, and use an anonymous function to call it with a particular argument, `typeWriter(el, "ACBDEF", () => runthis("x"));`

Answer (score 0):

You're creating more than one promises and only resolving the last one.
You could define the recursive function as an inner function, here is an example:

```
function typeWriter(element, text) {
    return new Promise (function(resolve,reject) {
        function recursion(txt) {
            element.textContent += txt.charAt(0);
            if (txt.length > 1) {
                var newText = txt.slice(1, txt.length);
                setTimeout(recursion, 150, newText);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        }
        recursion(text);
    });
}
```

Comment: could I also just return "resolve();" in the else part and move the "return new Promise" part into my "runThis()" function? maybe const typeWriterPromise = new Promise (function(resolve, reject) { typeWriter(element, text);}? And then the promise would be resolved out of the typewriter?

Comment: @PIcreamsoda I'm not sure I understand correctly what you're asking but the recursive function needs access to `resolve`. That is why I've defined it inside the promise where `resolve` is in scope.